# PHP Mail Message issue

Tags: php, email

When I try sending simple e-mails like this:

```
$email = 'example@mail.com';
$message = 'Hello.';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Example - No Reply <noreply@email.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($email,'Test',$message,$headers);
```

They work completely fine, but when I try to send a more complex message it just fails to do so :

```
$message = "<p>Thank you for registering with our system. In order to use it we need you to visit the following link:<br />
<a href='http://www.example.com/activate.php?q=$activation_link'>http://www.example.com/activate.php</a>
</p>"
```

I find this quite interesting. Is it possible that my host (iPage) has got some kind of filters that do not allow this? (Which is absurd) Or is it a mistake on my part?

Comment: Could be the HTML trips spam filters

Comment: have you any error or what you getting wrong in msg?

Comment: Do you get any errors while running the php code? If not, check the mail logs in the system to see if the mail was accepted.

Comment: @RakeshSharma No, the error logs are empty

Comment: Does your mailer fail (and you confirmed it) or has the email not arrived. Just for info, if you are testing towards hotmail you can forget your mail reaching it's destination (most of the times). HddnTHA has the solution, those work splendid and are easy to use. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @Matt The mail does not arrive. I'm testing towards gmail

Comment: Gmail is quite easy to work with, although have you checked your spam box. It usually ends up there. if it is, to counter that you can go the hard way by making an spf record, whitelist or something like that. Or just use phpmailer and solve it all in a heartbeat (it looks more daunting than it actually is, complete code is on github with an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this just got pretty obvious after more testing.
I am able to send all the e-mails if I exclude my domain name, which is pretty weird.

It's possible that my hosts filter is picking this up.
Going to have to see what's wrong with them.